# Optional brackets while calling delete in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I created an object, `Shape *shape = new Shape()`. Then i can free the memory using `delete` keyword. But there are two ways to write it :

```
delete (shape); //with brackets
```

and

```
delete shape; //without brackets
```

First is clear to understand that `shape` is an argument to `delete` function. But what about the second? What's happening under the hood?

Answer (score 6):

**delete** is not a function **but the operator** and the brackets does not mean calling it. You can branch variable name with brackets just because.

The example:

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = a;

    b = (a); //also ok
```

[You can read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(C%2B%2B)) about using of delete operator